# Can transmition of a packet finish before the first bit has reached the reciever?

Tags: asp.net

I should find a combination of the lenght of a packet, bandwidth and the link lenght and then find out if there is a combination for which transmitting time of a packet finishes before the first bit of the packet has reached the receiver. Is this even possible?

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing the answer to this. Pretty sure it depends on the protocol you're using. I am pretty sure there are fire and forget protocols for streaming audio and such but there are also protocols that confirm every packet received so you don't miss anything. Not my area of expertise though.

Answer (score 2):

TCP or UDP?

TCP will require to receive a response from the destination before it actually starts sending the packet thus it won't be possible here.

UDP has no concept of knowing whether or not the packet got received, which means that as soon as the packet has left the sender there is no further communication between the two.

Your question is worded ambiguously though: how can you talk about 'transmission time' (which implies the time between sending and receiving) while comparing that to the 'receiving time' (which is already part of the transmission time).?

Comment: this is a question from my book and it doesn't give any information about tcp or udp.